# UIScrollView as UIViewController's view and setting up background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a subclass of UIScrollView that I have set as the view of my UIViewController. I want to have a full screen background image that I can always see when I am scrolling throughout the UIScrollView. How can I do this? Please don't tell me to have the UIScrollView in front of a UIImageView. Trying to find alternative's to this. Right now I have a UIImageView as a subview of the UIScrollView, however when I scroll down to the bottom the image doesn't show anymore.

Comment: Why don't you want your scroll view in front of an image view? that's exactly how I'd do it.

Comment: because as I said I have my UIScrollView as the UIView of the UIViewController...

Comment: I would use a plain UIView as the view of your view controller, then embed both a UIImageView and a UIScrollView in that.

Comment: You want the image view behind.  Just make them both subviews of a third, normal UIView that is the UIViewController's view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override layout subviews in your UIScrollView subclass:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect frame = self.imageView.frame;
    frame.origin.y = self.contentOffset.y;
    self.imageView.frame = frame;
}
```

Throw in adjustments to x as well if desired.

Comment: Yes, but this will use CPU when you don't have to, and you have to write/run this code. I recommend one of the other solutions.

Comment: This answer is based on the user's requirements and not necessarily my personal recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your hierarchy by below way to save extra view.

- View Controller

  - View (Image View)

    - Scroll View

Answer (score 0):

Put two views inside your ViewController's UIView.  The first would be a UIImageView with the background image you want, and the second is the UIScrollView (with a clear background color so you can see the UIImageView's content (i.e., background image) through the scroll view).  In storyboard or IB, it would be structured something like this:

- View Controller

  - View

    - Image View
    - Scroll View

Answer (score 0):

Remove your UIScrollView from being the main view to the controller.

Instead, use a UIView and add the imageView ontop of the view, and the scroll view above that. Your layout should be as follows:

- UIViewController

  - root view

    - image view
    - scroll view

Now your view is layered properly to keep the image static and the scroll view above it

Hope this helps !